# Special Case of Universal Coefficient theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Show that if $C_* :$    $ ...\to C_2 \to C_1 \to C_0 \to 0$ be a complex of vector spaces over
 a field $k$, then $H^n$($Hom_k(C_*,k)) \cong$ $Hom_k(H_n(C_*),k)$.Does this result holds if $k$ is not a field?[Here $H_n$ and $H^n$ denotes the homology and cohomology groups respectively]

I'm unable to prove this.Any hints/ideas?

Comment: No, this doesn't hold if $k$ isn't a field. The discrepancy when $k$ is a PID is given by the universal coefficient theorem. In general there is a spectral sequence.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Can you give an example?Can u give hint for first part too?